# What is the relationship between Evil registers and ordinary Emacs registers/kill-ring?

Tags: evil, registers

I use `evil` and have gotten used to accessing the registers via `:registers` (in `normal-mode`).

This works fine for me except when I attempt to yank a URL or filename into a minibuffer prompt. In trying to fix this issue, I learned about Emacs registers, but they apparently have no relationship to the ones in `evil`, i.e. `M-x view-register 3` will be empty while `evil` register 3 contains a snippet of text. It seems like the two types of register are totally separate, is this the case?